# ng-repeat and collapse table

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display information inside a table using a button to show and hide the data in each row using the row's id, but since I have 2 ng-repeat, the first loop is completed before the second and therefore all the data is displayed in the same row : here is my code :

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
     <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th>Projet</th>
     <th>Responsable Apitech</th>
     <th>Temps Passé</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat-start="p in projetsListe" >
       <td>
       <button class="btn btn-xs" ng-click="expanded = !expanded" expand data-toggle="collapse" id="{{p.IdProjet}}" data-target=".{{p.IdProjet}}">
       <span ng-bind="expanded ? '-' : '+'"></span>
       </button>
       </td>
       <td>{{p.NomProjet}}</td>
       <td>{{p.ResponsableApitech}}</td>
       <td>Temps Passé</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="expanded">
         <td></td>
         <td colspan="6">
         <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
            <thead>
             <th></th>
             <th>Tache</th>
             <th>Collaborateur</th>
             <th>Date</th>
             <th>Temps Passé</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             <tr ng-repeat= "ft in ftListesorted" ng-show="expanded" class="collapse {{ft.IdProjet}}">
             <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></td>
             <td>{{ft.NomTache}}</td>
             <td>{{ft.NomCollaborateur}}</td>
             <td>{{ft.Datefeuillestemps |  date : 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
             <td>{{ft.TempsPasse}}</td>       
             </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

This is what im trying to achieve : http://embed.plnkr.co/qqNGSbw6oLUZbKqVQVpG/?show=preview

In my case : [image]

This is what I get instead : 
[image]

If you noticed in the second image get the information of the first and the second row while i want the information of each row seperatly.

Here is a plunker with an example of the problem : https://plnkr.co/edit/pPcPipLK0TltnOC60SSf

Answer (score 0):

create `expanded` property for each row. Change this lines

```
 <button class="btn btn-xs" ng-click="p.expanded = !p.expanded" expand data-
  toggle="collapse" id="{{p.IdProjet}}" data-target=".{{p.IdProjet}}">
```

and

```
  <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="p.expanded">
```

Comment: still the same result :(

Comment: you have `<tr ng-repeat= "ft in ftListesorted" ng-show="expanded" class="collapse {{ft.IdProjet}}">`.  Remove ng-show here

Comment: still the same problem :/